# MySQL; find and replace

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

In my MySQL database I've some strings like this:

`I'm something, Infos S. 12`

The pattern I want to search for is: `, Infos S.`, than a number (only digits) and than string end. It's case-insensitive.

How can I search for it and remove it?

I have this `I'm something, Infos S. 12` and I want `I'm something`.

This is what I have so far:

`UPDATE my_table SET title_col = REPLACE(title_col, SUBSTRING(title_col, LOCATE(', Infos S. ', title_col), LENGTH(title_col) - LOCATE(')', REVERSE(title_col)) - LOCATE(', Infos S. ', title_col) + 2), '') WHERE title_col LIKE '%(%)%';`

How to do the rest?

**Edit:**
If there's another comma it should get ignored.

Means: `I'm, something, Infos S. 12` (note the comma after `I'm`) should get `I'm, something`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp` to check if the column has the specified pattern and then use `substring` to update the string with substring upto the `,`.

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET title_col = SUBSTRING(title_col,1,locate(', Infos',title_col)-1) 
WHERE title_col regexp ', Infos S\\. [0-9]+$'
```

`regexp` match is case-insensitive by default. If you want to make it case-sensitive, use `regexp binary`.

```
where title_col regexp binary ', Infos S\\. [0-9]+$'
```

Comment: With case-insensitive you mean e.g. `infos` instead of `Infos`, right?

Comment: `The solution assumes there is no , before , Infos S. in the string.` That is't good. What can I do?

Comment: Okay, thanks. It doesn't make sense for me this way.